# Splitting a range of numbers up recursively with Python

Tags: python, recursion

I would like to write a recursive function in Python. I have written one but it doesn't work correctly.

I have a range of numbers from 1 to 1000 and I want cut it into two parts 1 to 500 and  501 to 1000. Then I want to do this recursively until there are only 20 numbers in each part.

Here is my attempt:

```
mw = range(1,1000)
def cuter(mw):
    if len(mw)<20:
        return False
    else:
        cut=int(len(mw)/2)
        number.append(mw[0])
        number.append(cut)
        number.append(mw[-1])   
        return cuter(mw)
cuter(mw)
```

Comment: So you want an award for obfuscated code...

Comment: Sounds like homework :\.

Comment: It a part of question, which is not a homework!
please help me with this

Comment: Don't you have a better description of the problems you have with this than "doesn't work"?

Comment: range(1,1000)[-20:] :

[1:500],[501:1000]

[1:250],[250:500],[501:750],[751:1000],.....

Comment: Is it ok if there are less than 20 numbers in a resulting part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this, where `seq` is a list with the range of numbers:

```
def cutter(seq):
    n = len(seq)
    if n <= 20:
        # here the recursion stops, do your stuff with the sequence
        return
    a = cutter(seq[:n/2])
    b = cutter(seq[n/2:])
    # combine the answer from both subsequences
    return
```